# Additional Query String in a Node Url

Tags: 7, uri

I'm not sure if this is possible in drupal 7, but I think I may have seen something like this happen before.  Let's say i added a content and you can see it at the url `http://mysite.com/my-article`.  In the content area, I'm displaying a block that's made by a custom module.  Right now, I have no problems going to a url like `http://mysite.com/my-article?var1=hello`, and then having my module responsible for creating the block to print `$_GET['var1']`.

However, the only change I would like to make is to have friendly urls.  I would prefer the url to be `http://mysite.com/my-article/hello`, then I would output the same content in my module block.   Is this easily do-able?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All is right what you are doing.

You cannot pass additional parts randomly with URL without adding them to menu registry and associating with callback.

Drupal uses `$_GET['q']` for default URL path and makes it SEO friendly. `$_GET['q']` can contain 9 parts in total in Drupal 7 (7 parts in Drupal 6). Each part can be accessed via `arg(n)` function.

Comment: thanks, can you show me an example of how to add to menu registry?

Comment: hook_menu() Docs: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7  Example: http://drupal.org/node/206764